# How to make your own scrollable Column like this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm new in flutter and I'm doing an app from dribble, do not know how to do this kinda scrolling
https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1837506/videos/32005/influenza_small.mp4

Please, can u show me how to make or share some links :)

Comment: Please add your code examples when asking questions. S.O. is not a discussion forum but used for solving specific code problems. Questions should be self-contained and not require video links. They must be examples that others can run to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Custom transitions applying on the PageViews

https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded

May be it will solve your problem, please do let me know. Happy coding

Comment: Thank you! Yes I'll try and respond soon

Answer (score 0):

Try using a PageView with vertical axis.

Take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1gE9xvph-A)

Comment: PageView doesn't support resizing, I need to resize in center

Comment: You can chain animations. Whatever widget you use as a child of pageview can have a SizeTransition

Comment: @ArgenZhukeev For resizing the particular UI element, try with Hero widget. It will help you to resize based on your parameters.